# spinning up multiple jenkins docker slaves for a single job

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am attempting to use this plugin to have docker slaves in jenkins https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Slaves+Plugin
However when I do I just get an unhelpful error:

```
Started by user test_admin
FATAL: null
xyz.quoidneufdocker.jenkins.dockerslaves.api.OneShotExecutorProvisioningException
    at xyz.quoidneufdocker.jenkins.dockerslaves.api.OneShotSlave.provisionFailed(OneShotSlave.java:146)
    at xyz.quoidneufdocker.jenkins.dockerslaves.api.OneShotSlave.provision(OneShotSlave.java:130)
    at xyz.quoidneufdocker.jenkins.dockerslaves.api.OneShotSlave.createLauncher(OneShotSlave.java:155)
    at xyz.quoidneufdocker.jenkins.dockerslaves.DockerSlave.createLauncher(DockerSlave.java:90)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.createLauncher(AbstractBuild.java:561)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:492)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am able to use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin without a problem, however I am not able to spin up side containers with that plugin.
Right now I need to spin up the main worker with 2 side containers (rabbitmq and mongo).

Comment: I am curious why this was moved to stack overflow. This is not code that I wrote and could boil down to a server configuration issue.

Comment: I would recommend using the `kubernetes-plugin` which allows you to spawn multiple containers per pod. You'll need to setup a kubernetes cluster though :)

Comment: I thought about using something like that, I had hoped for something a little more flexible on a per job basis like the plugin I was looking at. But I guess worst case that is an option

Comment: Migration is mainly about target audience and the likelihood of getting a good answer: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8648/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Kubernetes can be a time-consuming task. Instead I suggest using [Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/chapter-docker-workflow.html) and define the job using Pipeline. You'll need Jenkins 2.0+, but this is backwards compatible, so no problem updating.

The Docker plugin for Pipeline allows you to start several containers and stop them later (have a look at `Image.run`). Furthermore, you can run arbitrary commands easily. You can even decide on which Jenkins node to run your containers.

Comment: The way I have the above setup is it runs the container on a separate docker host.  
Looking and trying out this plugin does not seem that doing that is supported well. I tried the syntax under "Specifying a custom server" and it just tries to spin up the container on the jenkins box. I can't find where to specify a global default server (if it is possible)

Comment: I did figure a somewhat solution by making the docker host a slave, that just does not seem right though. Especially when using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin I had no executers on this box (but it is a solution)

Comment: In attempting to use the Image.run, I keep getting `Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject getProperty java.lang.String (org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.run)`. Same thing when I try to save the Docker.image('whatever') to a variable and do variable.run, or if I just do Docker.image('whatever').run

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36297443/6778209) may work for you. Notice how `def container = image.run('--name ' + DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)` is capturing the running container.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I still need to figure out how best to handle multiple instances of this job running when it comes to ports (each instance will need its own stack of containers). But this at least points me in the right direction.

Comment: Hummm,that's a thing for docker network, so that each stack can be run isolated. You can setup a network for each stack, and then pass in the --network parameter to `image.run`.