# Escaping parameters with white space in the docker .withRun command in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Currently unable to get my head around how to correctly pass my parameters from Jenkins, to the docker .withRun function, in Jenkins Docker Plugin (specifically in declarative pipelines), which contain whitespace.

Tried an unknown amount of methods to get this working and currently at a loss. See code below

```
        stage('Send Notifications')
        {
            steps
            {
            // Send a notification based on the parameters passed
                script
                {
                    docker.withRegistry(registry, registryCredentials)
                    {
                        // echo "${TITLE}"
                        docker.image("notifications:latest").withRun("--rm -e TITLE=\"${TITLE}\" -e MESSAGE=\"${MESSAGE}\" -e MESSAGE_FORMAT=\"${MESSAGE_TYPE}\" -e EMAIL=\"${EMAILS}\" --name notifications notifications")
                        // sh "docker run --rm -e TITLE=\"${TITLE}\" -e MESSAGE=\"${MESSAGE}\" -e MESSAGE_FORMAT=\"${MESSAGE_TYPE}\" -e EMAIL=\"${EMAILS}\" --name notifications notifications"

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Currently if I just use the shell command method it works perfectly. However using the Docker Plugin method I just can't get it to work.

```
Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] {
Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image withRun org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl). Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
```

Any advice would be a help, just trying to create notifications that take in strings from other pipelines. So I can send messages to different forms of communication (currently working on slack).

EDIT: Added this in and has just produced another error. What I am trying to achieve is passing parameters into the args that will be lines of text (a message to the user of a failed build from another job).

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.withRun() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values
```

```
docker.withRegistry(registry, registryCredentials)
                    {
                        def args = "--rm -e TITLE=\"This is a message\" -e MESSAGE=\"a message\" -e MESSAGE_FORMAT=\"s\" -e EMAIL=\"asdf@email.com\" --name notifications notifications"
                        echo args
                        docker.image("notifications:latest").withRun(args)
                        //sh "docker run --rm -e TITLE=\"${TITLE}\" -e MESSAGE=\"${MESSAGE}\" -e MESSAGE_FORMAT=\"${MESSAGE_TYPE}\" -e EMAIL=\"${EMAILS}\" --name notifications notifications"
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject
>   invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object
>   (org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image withRun
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl). Administrators can decide
>   whether to approve or reject this signature.

You could just go to Jenkins' [administration panel and approve those](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/). 
[image]

EDIT:

As for your other issue. The correct usage of `withRun`

```
node {
    checkout scm

    docker.withServer('tcp://swarm.example.com:2376', 'swarm-certs') {
        docker.image('mysql:5').withRun('-p 3306:3306') {
            /* do things */
        }
    }
}
```

Do notice that `withRun` arguments are parameters for the container to start with, it expects a clause with expressions to execute. Which for your case would mean

```
docker.image("notifications:latest").withRun() {
    sh "docker run --rm -e TITLE=\"${TITLE}\" -e MESSAGE=\"${MESSAGE}\" -e MESSAGE_FORMAT=\"${MESSAGE_TYPE}\" -e EMAIL=\"${EMAILS}\" --name notifications notifications"
}
```

Or even simpler

```
    docker.image('notifications:latest').inside {
        sh "docker run --rm -e TITLE=\"${TITLE}\" -e MESSAGE=\"${MESSAGE}\" -e MESSAGE_FORMAT=\"${MESSAGE_TYPE}\" -e EMAIL=\"${EMAILS}\" --name notifications notifications"
    }
```

EDIT2:

to use those just as container parameters, please do:

```
docker.image("notifications:latest").withRun("-e TITLE=\"${TITLE}\" -e MESSAGE=\"${MESSAGE}\" -e MESSAGE_FORMAT=\"${MESSAGE_TYPE}\" -e EMAIL=\"${EMAILS}\" --name notifications notifications") {}
```

EDIT3:

Alternatively you could just start it as an agent for given stage

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'notifications:latest'
                registryUrl 'registry'
                registryCredentialsId 'registryCredentials'
                args "-e TITLE=\"This is a message\" -e MESSAGE=\"a message\" -e MESSAGE_FORMAT=\"s\" -e EMAIL=\"asdf@email.com\" --name notifications notifications"
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "I'm in container"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Approved the script and has just produced an error if you see in my edit section I am just passing a message that will contain whitespace so without quotes the message would be seen as additional arguments. If you have any advice on a better solution to do this please let me know.

Comment: Followed up on you

Comment: Maybe it's my misunderstanding of withRun then, as the docker container is very short lived. It's only objective is to take in these 4 parameters and send out a message and close. No commands are actually run inside the container. So in this case is just running the shell script the advised solution? As those last two to me seem like you are running the shell script inside the container.

Comment: I wonder what's the minimum that withRun requires, it might be that you need to execute a clause `.withRun(args) {c -> sh "echo test"}` like anything there. which isn't the nicest of situations you can find yourself in.

Comment: found a declarative pipeline way to do that, do let me know if that works for you

Comment: Brill that works thanks. Knew it was something obvious I was missing. For anyone else reading this, the important part if using EDIT:2 is the {} block at the end. EDIT:3 might work also but going with the previous as it looks cleaner.

Comment: always glad to help.

Comment: In general, **never approve `GroovyObject invokeMethod`**. If you get a "not permitted" error about `GroovyObject invokeMethod`, it doesn't mean what the error message says. What it means is "can't find method" (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60233170/107331, where a method name is misspelled). Here, the issue is that `withRun` requires a closure block to follow it, which originally wasn't there.