# Groovy object's method invokeMethod in Jenkins sandbox mode

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to implement decorator pattern in my jenkins shared library.
I want to decorate '*timeout-try-catch*' block, so whenever some method of some class invoked (decorator doesnt care what class is that and what method is that), it automatically being wrapped in *timeout-try-catch* block.
But for that, I need to override method 'invokeMethod' in decorator class. Here is the smallest piece of code in Jenkinsfile that causes error:

```
node {
    sh 'echo "the content"'
    new MyClass().doSomething() // output: doSomething
}

class MyClass {
    def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
        println name
    }
}
```

And I get following error:
**org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (MyClass doSomething)**

Is that any way to override invokeMethod or implement dynamic decorator pattern (which doesnt cares about decorating class and it's methods) without exiting Jenkins's 'sandbox' mode?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have admin access, you could go and specifically approve the use of that method (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56023403/107331 ), though be aware that if you have non-admin users submitting jobs on your Jenkins instance that method can be a dangerous one to simply approve.

Another option is to approve each script that uses this decorator.